# ARM Deployment failed due to dependOn in EdgeNode on HDI cluster

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-rm-template

I want to create 2 edge nodes in HDI cluster using ARM template. I need to have Edge node 2 is depends on Edge node 1

Here is my ARM template for Edge node:-

```
  {
    "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'),'/', parameters('TestEdgenodeName1'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/applications",
    "apiVersion": "2015-03-01-preview",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/', parameters('clusterName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "marketPlaceIdentifier": "TestEdgeNode1",
        "computeProfile": {
            "roles": [{
                "name": "edgenode",
                "targetInstanceCount": 1,
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('EdgenodeSize1')]"
                }
            }]
        },
        "installScriptActions": [{
            "name": "[concat('node','-' ,uniquestring(parameters('TestEdgenodeName1')))]",
            "uri": "[variables('InstallationScript1')]",
            "parameters": "",
            "roles": ["edgenode"]
        }],
        "uninstallScriptActions": [],
        "httpsEndpoints": [],
        "applicationType": "CustomApplication"
    }
 }
    "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'),'/', parameters('TestEdgenodeName2'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/applications",
    "apiVersion": "2015-03-01-preview",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/applications/', parameters('clusterName'), '/', parameters('TestEdgenodeName1'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "marketPlaceIdentifier": "TestEdgeNode2",
        "computeProfile": {
            "roles": [{
                "name": "edgenode",
                "targetInstanceCount": 1,
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('EdgenodeSize2')]"
                }
            }]
        },
        "installScriptActions": [{
            "name": "[concat('node','-' ,uniquestring(parameters('TestEdgenodeName2')))]",
            "uri": "[variables('installationScript2')]",
            "parameters": "",
            "roles": ["edgenode"]
        }],
        "uninstallScriptActions": [],
        "httpsEndpoints": [],
        "applicationType": "CustomApplication"
    }
 }
```

I am getting the below error when deploying ARM template.

```
InvalidTemplate : Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/applications/test-cluster/test-edgenode' is not defined in the template.
```

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight supports single edge node at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the issue by using the below on second edge node.

```
     "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/applications', parameters('clusterName'), parameters('TestEdgenodeName1'))]"
        ],
```